# Does anyone know if Python 2.7 is compatible with postgresql RDS version 14.4?

Tags: python, python-2.7, amazon-rds, psycopg2, postgresql-14

We are currently trying to upgrade our PostgresSQL RDS version from 10 to 14.4
We have our Django instance runs on python version 2.7- and connects to RDS.

We use psycopg2 lib and want to see its compatibility

I was looking for any documentation which might state regarding compatibility between python and postgres version.

Else we will need to upgrade the python version first before the postgres Version